# Combining Tables | PowerBI vs VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, powerquery

I needed recently to divide tables, fill in the subtables and then combine it in Excel.

Unfortunately, I needed to extract subsets of columns and then subsets of rows.

Combining everything to the master table is a bit time consuming with excel formulas, therefore, I wondered about automation.

I could do it with VBA but creating a reliable tool would take sometime.

I started recently to use Power BI/Power Query and wondered whether it would be a more efficient way to do it.

Do you think it makes sense to do it in Power Query/Power BI using M?

It seems to me that it may not be efficient but I started using M quite recently so I wanted to ask more experienced users whether it makes sense to approach it this way.

Basicaly I have a master Table 1 that needs filling in. It can have as many as 30 columns or more and a few dozens of thousands rows.

**Table 1**

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |

I would like to create a table like Table 2.

**Table 2**

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | C |
| 2 | A | A | C |
| 3 | B | B | C |
| 4 | B | B | C |
| 5 | D | D | D |

There would letters like A - Z used for assignment. Basically, it could be any combination of them.

Based on Table 2, I would like to create tables like Table 3 - 6.

**Table 3**

| ID | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A |
| 2 | A | A |

**Table 4**

| ID | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | B | B |
| 4 | B | B |

**Table 5**

| ID | Col3 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | C |

**Table 6**

| ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | D | D | D |

After the actual data is inputted in the Tables 3 - 6, I would like to merge them into Table 1 but with the data inputted.

There may be dozens of tables like Tables 3 - 6.

Could you please advise me what would be the best solution to do it?

VBA or Power BI?

Comment: Combination of Power Query and VBA (if the last is needed). Your example is too general, I'd suggest to tackle the problem in bits and report back with specific issues

Comment: @Ricardo, Thank you for your response. I know it is quite general but I am wondering what would be an easy approach to do it. The most important part is joing the tables. My approach would be basically to unpivot the master table and then perform vlookup (index/match etc.) based on the ID and Assignment A/B/C... (ID should be unique but unfortunately it is not always so I want to double check). It should be a workbook with the master table and a folder with any number of the subset tables that get combined when placed there. Is there any easier approach to do it in the power query?